# avoid auto generation of name in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, attributes, unique-id

the code below protects the server from generating unique but new name is always generated for the name attribute,  but i want to deny new name generation, please help me

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text1" name ="text1" Text="20" ClientIDMode="Static" />:
```

Regards

Comment: Dears, 
the code below protects the server from generating unique but new name is always generated for the name attribute,  but i want to deny new name generation, please help me

ClientIDMode="Static" 
Regards

Comment: There is no "name" attribute for TextBox.